# Sum along diagonal and anti-diagonal lines in 2D array - NumPy / Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, diagonal

I have a np array like below:

```
np.array([[1,0,0],[1,0,0],[0,1,0]])
output:
array([[1, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0]])
```

I wish to sum left diagonal and right right diagonal line elements to new array:

1) left diagonal line :

[image]

out put:

```
[1,1,0,1,0]
```

2) right diagonal line:

[image]

out put:

```
[0,0,1,2,0]
```

Is there an easy way? Thanks~

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use [`.diag`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.diag.html) like this:

```py
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([[1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0]])

left_diag = [np.sum(np.diag(np.fliplr(arr), d)) for d in range(len(arr) - 1, -len(arr), -1)]
right_diag = [np.sum(np.diag(arr, d)) for d in range(len(arr) - 1, -len(arr), -1)]

print("left:", left_diag)
print("right:", right_diag)
```

Output:

```
left: [1, 1, 0, 1, 0]
right: [0, 0, 1, 2, 0]
```

it returns all the element in a diagonal of a given offset. to get all the offsets in the order you mentioned, we go from +2 to -2, then for each diagonal get the sum of elements.

to get the left diagonal we first flip arr using [`.fliplr`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fliplr.html)

Answer (score 3):

**Approach #1 : Using masking**

Here's a vectorized one based on `masking` -

```
def left_diag_sum_masking(a):
    n = len(a)
    N = 2*n-1

    R = np.arange(N)
    r = np.arange(n)

    mask = (r[:,None] <= R) & (r[:,None]+n > R)

    b = np.zeros(mask.shape,dtype=a.dtype)
    b[mask] = a.ravel()

    return b.sum(0)
```

So, `left_diag_sum_masking` gives us left-diagonal summations. To get the right-diagonal ones, simply flip along cols, sum and then flip it back.

Hence, simply do -

```
right_diag_sum = left_diag_sum_masking(a[::-1])[::-1]
```

Sample run -

```
In [220]: np.random.seed(0)

In [221]: a = np.random.randint(0,9,(4,4))

In [222]: a
Out[222]: 
array([[5, 0, 3, 3],
       [7, 3, 5, 2],
       [4, 7, 6, 8],
       [8, 1, 6, 7]])

In [223]: left_diag_sum_masking(a)
Out[223]: array([ 5,  7, 10, 23,  9, 14,  7])

In [224]: left_diag_sum_masking(a[::-1])[::-1] # right-diag sums
Out[224]: array([ 3,  5, 13, 21, 20,  5,  8])
```

**Approach #2 : Using zeros-padding**

```
def left_diag_sum_zerospad(a):
    n = len(a)
    N = 2*n-1
    p = np.zeros((n,n),dtype=a.dtype)
    ap = np.concatenate((a,p),axis=1)
    return ap.ravel()[:n*N].reshape(n,-1).sum(0)
```

To get right-diagonal summations -

```
right_diag_sum = left_diag_sum_zerospad(a[::-1])[::-1]
```

Comment: Your solution fails for non-square matrices. Check my answer for the code that should work in an arbitrary case.

Answer (score 3):

Yet another method, based on padding and rolling:

```py
def sum_shifted(arr, direction=1):
    n = arr.shape[0]
    temp = np.zeros((n, 2 * n - 1), dtype=arr.dtype)
    temp[:, slice(None, n) if direction == 1 else slice(-n, None)] = arr
    for i in range(n):
        temp[i, :] = np.roll(temp[i, :], direction * i)
    return np.sum(temp, 0)[::direction]
```

This gives you plenty of options.
Speedwise, @Divakar's methods seems to have an edge:

[image: benchmarks]

These plots were generated with [this script](https://github.com/norok2/BenchmarkTemplateIPY/blob/master/BenchmarkingTemplate.ipynb) using these as test functions:

```py
def sum_shifted(arr, direction=1):
    n = arr.shape[0]
    temp = np.zeros((n, 2 * n - 1), dtype=arr.dtype)
    temp[:, slice(None, n) if direction == 1 else slice(-n, None)] = arr
    for i in range(n):
        temp[i, :] = np.roll(temp[i, :], direction * i)
    return np.sum(temp, 0)[::direction]


def sum_shifted_both(arr):
    return sum_shifted(arr, 1), sum_shifted(arr, -1)


def sum_adam(arr):
    return (
        np.array([np.sum(np.diag(np.fliplr(arr), d)) for d in range(len(arr) - 1, -len(arr), -1)]),
        np.array([np.sum(np.diag(arr, d)) for d in range(len(arr) - 1, -len(arr), -1)]))


def sum_divakar(a):
    n = len(a)
    N = 2*n-1

    R = np.arange(N)
    r = np.arange(n)

    mask = (r[:,None] <= R) & (r[:,None]+n > R)

    b_leftdiag = np.zeros(mask.shape,dtype=a.dtype)
    b_leftdiag[mask] = a.ravel()

    b_rightdiag = np.zeros(mask.shape,dtype=a.dtype)
    b_rightdiag[mask[:,::-1]] = a.ravel()

    return b_leftdiag.sum(0), b_rightdiag.sum(0)[::-1]


def sum_divakar2(a):
    def left_sum(a):
        n = len(a)
        N = 2*n-1
        p = np.zeros((n,n),dtype=a.dtype)
        ap = np.concatenate((a,p),axis=1)
        return ap.ravel()[:n*N].reshape(n,-1).sum(0)

    return left_sum(a), left_sum(a[::-1])[::-1]
```

and as helper functions:

```
def gen_input(n):
    return np.arange(n * n).reshape((n, n))


def equal_output(out_a, out_b):
    return all(
        np.all(a_arr == b_arr)
        for a_arr, b_arr in zip(out_a, out_b))


input_sizes=(5, 10, 50, 100, 500, 1000, 5000)
funcs = sum_shifted_both, sum_adam, sum_divakar, sum_divakar2


runtimes, input_sizes, labels, results = benchmark(
    funcs, gen_input=gen_input, equal_output=equal_output, input_sizes=input_sizes)

plot_benchmarks(runtimes, input_sizes, labels)
```

Answer (score 0):

A fast solution that works even for non-square matrices:

```py
from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import as_strided


def left_diag_sum(matrix):

    n_rows, n_cols = matrix.shape
    if n_rows > n_cols:
        matrix = matrix.T
        n_rows, n_cols = n_cols, n_rows
    diag_len = n_rows
    n_diags  = n_rows + n_cols - 1

    dtype   = matrix.dtype
    leaning = np.zeros((diag_len, n_diags), dtype)

    col_dim_stride = dtype.itemsize
    row_dim_stride = col_dim_stride * (n_diags + 1)

    strided      = as_strided(leaning, matrix.shape, (row_dim_stride, col_dim_stride))
    strided[...] = matrix

    return leaning.sum(0)


def right_diag_sum(matrix):

    row_reversed_matrix = matrix[::-1]
    return left_diag_sum(row_reversed_matrix)[::-1]
```

Answer (score -1):

numpy as a very useful function for this trace here is an example

'''
   import numpy as np
   a=np.array([[1,0,0],[1,0,0],[0,1,0]])
   b=np.trace(a)
   print(b)
'''
[Here is the link to documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.trace.html)